# what type of hash?(md5, sha1)

Tags: php, hash

seems to PassHash sha1, and Secret(maybe salt) md5

i am already trying many hash algoritm(using hashcat)
but no result..

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    if ($_POST["username"] == "" || $_POST["password"] == "" || $_POST["email"] == "")
        stderr("Error", "Missing form data.");
    if ($_POST["password"] != $_POST["password2"])
        stderr("Error", "Passwords mismatch.");
    if (!validemail($_POST['email']))
        stderr("Error", "Not valid email");

    $username = sqlesc($_POST["username"]);
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $email = sqlesc($_POST["email"]);
    $secret = mksecret();
    $passhash = sqlesc(md5($secret . $password . $secret));
    $secret = sqlesc($secret);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (added, last_access, secret, username, passhash, status, email) VALUES(NOW(), NOW(), $secret, $username, $passhash, 'confirmed', $email)") or sqlerr(__FILE__, __LINE__);
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=$username");
    $arr = mysql_fetch_row($res);
    if (!$arr)
        stderr("Error", "Unable to create the account. The user name is possibly already taken.");
    header("Location: $BASEURL/userdetails.php?id=$arr[0]");
    die;
}
```

this code https://github.com/mlangill/biotorrents/blob/master/adduser.php

what type of hash is this?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

The hash (7d022cb232c1245fcfe03584477ca247c4efeefe) has 40 chars which make it look like [SHA1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1).

[MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) hashes just has 32 chars.

You're using [salted hashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) for password hashing in your example.  e1e69fc477abad67f92d7e8fc824d29f6e03d776 is the sha1sum and wf678r4mk4boix98rfrgefa0zzelka97 seems to be the salt.

Comment: Hashes are one-way functions, so there is no (easy) way to decrypt them.

Comment: You're using salted hashes for password hashing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29, e1e69fc477abad67f92d7e8fc824d29f6e03d776 is the sha1sum and wf678r4mk4boix98rfrgefa0zzelka97 is the salt.

Comment: yes i know. i am using hashcat and passwordspro, john the ripper. but i can't find sha1(40 lenght):md5(32 lenght) format